# How to define a type when I only know the pattern for that object's keys?

Tags: typescript

I have a function expecting an object with keys like `'mykey-0'`, `'myotherkey-0'`, `'mykey-1'`, `'myotherkey-1'`, etc.

The thing is that I don't know if there will be any of these two keys, and I don't know what the number will be (it increases)

How can I express a TS type for these optional keys? Something like `{ 'mykey-*'?: string, 'myotherkey-*'?: string, otherprop: string }`.

Comment: There is no support for this.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that can reasonably *typed* for, it's simply something your code needs to process at runtime.

Comment: So then is there a better way to stop TS from yelling at it than `@ts-ignore` everywhere I use that function? I might as well type it `any`.

Comment: The least or best you can do is create an indexed type like so: `const obj: { [key: string]: string } = { }`;

Comment: If the property names are fixed/known at compile-time, `Partial` might do what you want, but it's not clear from the question what exactly you do want.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys(obj)

This function will return array of keys

So you will be able to make your process over them.

Comment: How does that help Typescript typing?

Comment: Do you mean by typing -> type annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not an answer for your direct question as your data structure is just wrongly made. Fact that you have iterator in the end of every key means it probably should be an array. Consider how I would model such:

```
type MyData = {
  mykey: string,
  myotherkey: string
}
type ArrMyData = MyData[]

function f(arr: ArrMyData) {
    return arr.map(el => el.mykey) // example transformation
}
```

Such structure also fixes your issue with optionally, as just the element will not be in the array. Done.

In summary - lets try to use proper data structures instead of inventing the wheel.
I wrote more info about how we should think about state modeling, consider reading maybe it will help - [State modeling is your responsibility](https://dev.to/macsikora/modeling-the-state-is-your-responsibility-207f)

---

If such kind of data is forced by the server we need to transform it instead of propagating invalid structure and deal with it. Popular pattern for such is `Decoder`, BTW - its the one and only why to deal with server side data in Elm architecture. Such decoder will be typed as `WrongDataStructure -> CorrectDataStructure`. So lets write such decoder:

```
type ApiResponse = Record<string, string>

type WantedData = {
  mykey: string,
  myotherkey: string
}
type ArrMyData = WantedData[]

function decoder(data: ApiResponse): ArrMyData {
    const keys = Object.keys(data);
    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        let i: string | number = key.match(/-([0-9])$/)?.[1] ?? '0';
        i = parseInt(i)
        const cleanKey = key.replace(/-([0-9])$/, '') // remove the index
        if (!acc[i]) {
            acc.push({[cleanKey]: data[key]} as WantedData)
        } else {
            acc[i] = {...acc[i], [cleanKey]: data[key]}
        }
        return acc;
    } ,[] as ArrMyData)
}

const response = { 'mykey-0': 'a', 'myotherkey-0': 'b', 'mykey-1': 'c', 'myotherkey-1': 'd' };
const data = decoder(response);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=25&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWAlCBnMB7Adi6BeKyAxugE4AmAPCsCfJgOYA0U1tDAfAFCeiRQDqAQ0zAIZACKDggqPgDenKFAC2IANYQQALhY06TRSpDpgACwgkN23W3qcAvj3DQYJEgFkQk6bIHDRElKCANoAutwAZgCumITA8FhQZBDEySQAFGRBOnBIqBjYEACUOW6e3jIKSkrE2MBQVii%20APIARgBWKcAAdI2ZQUUA3IZKJBDAUSSYDZoo3WNkUYQQ6emChITMVkWy7FBV1YcANuNQ8Dqs%20lAAPlCYUcqtFr5W3cpShKbpAPQAtOnBAAMvwAnKEigASb5FAD83WCAEZQlAYTCoAByQHo4aHQ7wXxgQQkHAASRE6XgRRGuNq1CghBOwgA0poXpp5hAwEd1is-gDgWDId9mOj0Ttvt8oGNlOgAG7QMzQOjJAAe1LxESg6QAhOtCMF4OD9urcUo9d0wFEUF85MEGRBmZpQjostJglZQvYoIImkIRGIKlTTUovRAjjhjcHcXqDcj5N0EzHDcw7YzMCyQM6kkF3U7HFH88GxhMpt6Njjql7GGFvU1XB4vAMHNxafUxmgsBH5BjVFZflidOjBOiRaoTOZLJp%20%20jB60Rz31FOETOMYR5%20ix4rJyBfsvB2R0VB7MNW9mfPhkqkLOl2wUcEMgA)

What we are doing is kinda a gate when we take the structure and make it more approachable. My implementation is only example.

Comment: I realize it's not the best data structure, but it comes from a query string in the URL from which I have to rebuild a saner object. The type issue is on the function that rebuilds the object from the query string.

Comment: Then make a decoder which will transform it into proper one

Comment: I will write one in the answer, watch out :D

Comment: Made one I hope you get what I mean.